# Android Studio -Launcher Activity not starting

Tags: android, android-activity, startup

In my android app , my Launcher Activity is not starting.
My Activity ( LoginActivity ) is not starting , instead my MainActivity is starting??

My Manifest :

```
 <application

>             android:allowBackup="true"
>             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>             android:label="@string/app_name"
>             android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>             android:supportsRtl="true"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>             android:name=".App"
>             >
>             <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
>                 <intent-filter>
>                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>     
>                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>                 </intent-filter>
>             </activity>
>             <activity android:name=".HowActivity" />
>             <activity android:name=".RulesActivity" />
>             <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
>             <activity android:name=".PayActivity" />
>         </application>
>     
>     </manifest>
```

And my Settings :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU7yI.png)

When I start my app from compiler , it goes to LoginActivity , but when i start from my phone it goes to Main Activity

Comment: dunno maybe uninstall/install again the app on the phone

Comment: Check your LoginActivity code. Its navigating to MainActivity i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you previously installed your app with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

linked to your `MainActivity` then your Launcher remembered that `MainActivity` is your default activity. You can use `activity-alias` or simply uninstall your app and install again

Comment: if the compiler detects any manifest change doesn't it perform e full install ?? i'm not sure does it ?